# How to debug a SystemError in Python?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application which uses the requests library and gives this exception when running lots of threads at once:

```
SystemError: error return without exception set
Exception ignored in: <generator object iter_slices at 0x000001CF11144CA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 449, in iter_slices
    def iter_slices(string, slice_length):
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

I'm struggling to debug it because I can't reproduce it in a simpler application, I can't figure out how to log it better or connect a debugger, and I can only find one other mention of this online, which has no solution:
https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4367

I would appreciate any pointers where to go next!

Comment: Do you have any idea where this happens? If you can provide some more of the context (in the form of code) it would be helpful.

Comment: This error usually means there's a bug in a C extension function that's sitting in between two Python functions on the stack, typically because whoever wrote it never expected your inner function to raise so they didn't test for it very well. Which means there's actually two super-fun debugging things to do—track down the bug in someone else's code so you can report it upstream, and track down what your code is doing to trigger it so you can implement a workaround while you wait for them to fix the bug.

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier It appears to be mostly while POSTing files with requests, but it only appears with lots of threads active so it's hard to totally sure in the log

Comment: The `Exception ignored in: <generator ...` message sounds like the exception occurred while a generator was being garbage-collected.

Comment: For conccurrent http requests consider twisted/treq or asyncio/aiohttp.  If you are scraping, perhaps a dedicated tool like scrapy (built on twisted).  But you may just be threading without proper accounting for the associated hazards.  Hard to say without full code.